# replace block within {{ super() }}

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I have a base template which includes a block for the default `<head>` content. Within the head block, there's a block for the `<title>`.

For example, in the base file I would have:

```
<head>
    {% block head %}
    {% block title %}<title>An App</title>{% endblock title %}
    <script src="somescript.js"></script>
    {% endblock head %}
</head>
```

In the child template, I would like to include everything that was in the head block from the base (by calling `{{ super()) }}` and include some additional things, yet at the same time replace the title block within the super call.

Is there a way to do this without just putting a block around the rest of the head content (excluding the title) and just replacing all of that?

Comment: Super is good for when you have a series of templates calling each other and maybe want to add a style-sheet for each template called. For those that want to see an example, the official documentation has a good one: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#child-template

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't call `super`. In your child template you can do:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}<title>This is my new TITLE</title>{% endblock %}
```

Jinja replaces all the blocks in the parent by the ones defined in the child, if you do not provide a new definition it uses the definition in the parent. So it will render as:

```
<head>

    <title>TITLE</title>
    <script src="somescript.js"></script>

</head>
```

You call `super` if you want the default value of the block in the parent:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}<title>TITLE</title>{{ super() }}{% endblock %}
```

And this renders as:

```
<head>

    <title>TITLE</title><title>An App</title>
    <script src="somescript.js"></script>

</head>
```

If you want to add more scripts just make a place holder block in your base template:

```
<head>
    {% block head %}
    {% block title %}<title>An App</title>{% endblock title %}
    <script src="somescript.js"></script>
    {% block moreScripts %}{% endblock moreScripts %}
    {% endblock head %}
</head>
```

And use it as in :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}<title>TITLE</title>{% endblock %}
{% block moreScripts %}
<script src="somescript1.js"></script>
<script src="somescript2.js"></script>
<script src="somescript3.js"></script>
{% endblock moreScripts %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Great explanation. Is this the best strategy for handling separation of logic? Are there other ways to achieve the same thing? I've got separate pages each needing a different js scripts which the above works great for. I'm slightly confused as to the best approach.

Comment: I think this is a good approach for your issue, it is the intended solution for problems like yours IMHO. As far as the separation of the scripts has no logic involved this is the right solution. You can think about it as a design flexibility...

Comment: Very good explanation. With the moreScripts block are we supposed to close it with endblock moreScripts rather than endblock title? I am still new and learning about Jinja.

Answer (score 3):

#### Note:

If the application needs to add its own content to a block that already has some content, then *Jinja2*’s `super()` function **must be used**.

For example, this is how the scripts block would need to be written in the derived template to add a new *JavaScript* file to the document:

```html
{% block scripts %}
  {{ super() }}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="my-script.js"></script> 
{% endblock %}
```