# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: there is no parent block called 'scripts'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I get the following error when I try to run my app.

```
  File "/Users/ccc/microblog/app/templates/errors/500.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "base.html" %}
  File "/Users/ccc/microblog/app/templates/base.html", line 48, in top-level template code
    {% block scripts %}
  File "/Users/ccc/microblog/app/templates/base.html", line 49, in block "scripts"
    {{ super() }}
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: there is no parent block called 'scripts'.
```

I am following Miguel's Flask lessons and it seems like our code is largely similar. Hence I am not too sure this error appears.
This does not happen when I remove {{super()}} from the block script. The code runs smoothly then.

Here is my code for the base.html:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  {% block navbar %}
   <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-header">
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">Microblog</a>
           </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
               <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                   <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.explore') }}">Explore</a></li>
                   <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.add_habit') }}">Habits</a></li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                   {% if current_user.is_anonymous %}
                   <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Login</a></li>
                   {% else %}
                   <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.user', username=current_user.username) }}">Profile</a></li>
                   <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
                   {% endif %}
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
       <hr>
   </nav>
  {% endblock %}

  {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">{{ message }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% endwith %}

        {# application content needs to be provided in the app_content block #}
        <br>
        {% block app_content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  {% endblock %}

  {% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    {{ moment.include_jquery() }}
    {{ moment.include_moment() }}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  {% endblock %}
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace block within {{ super() }}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267620/replace-block-within-super)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message said it right: you cannot use `super()` in your `base.html` template since it does not have a parent template. `super()` can be used [only in a child template](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/). When you put `{{ super() }}` into a block in a child template it will include the block's content from the parent template. E.g. if you want to add an additional script in the `child.html` you can write:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block scripts %}
  {{ super() }}
  <script src="https://cnd.com/path.to.script.js></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Now it will include *all* scripts from the parent and this one as well.